# C# Sort an array by absolute value does not work as intended with a input array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

Sorting arrays by absolute value using a input array refuses to work but replacing it with a simple array works. I have no idea why it doesn't work, I just don't see what is wrong.

I need the result to be like this:

Input: `-5 4 8 -2 1`

Output: `1 -2 4 -5 8`

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var sampleInput =  Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

        int[] x = sampleInput;
        int n = sampleInput.Length;
            int[] output = new int[n];
            string sOutput = string.Empty;
            int start = 0;
            int last = n - 1;

            while (last >= start)
            {
                n--;
                if (Math.Abs(x[start]) > Math.Abs(x[last]))
                {
                    output[n] = x[start++];
                }
                else
                {
                    output[n] = x[last--];
                }

                sOutput = output[n].ToString() + " " + sOutput;
            }

            Console.Write(sOutput);

    }
```

Comment: For those assisting, be aware the OP is likely using this code -https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/1537/sorting-sorted-array-as-per-absolute-value-with-time-complexity-on-in-c-sharp.aspx .

Comment: Writing a sort algorythm in code is generally more trouble then it is worth. It is a higher math problem, not really a programming one. There is existing, excessively tested code out there, made by people that understand all the nitty, gritty details of the underlying math. Aside from learning how they work, you should propably just treat it like a blackbox. I would just give Array.Sort() a custom comparer. Or use the LINQ approach providfed by zaitsman, because it is shorter and still clearly understandable.

Comment: "Im not sure what exactly I need, that is the core of the problem." Answer us and yourself these questions: 1. What do you want to sort? 2. How do you want to sort it? 3. Why do you want to sort it that way? | Particular if you go into sorting class instances, there is often a dozen ways to skin the particular feline - and each of the might be valid at one time or another.  The GUI technology you are using also plays a role.

Answer (score 8):

why not

```
using System.Linq;

var sorted = new [] {-5, 4, 8, -2 , 1}.OrderBy(Math.Abs);
```

(and of course to get an Array, you can tack on a `.ToArray()` at the end there).

And to pass what you want:

```
var sampleInput =  Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
var sorted = sampleInput.OrderBy(Math.Abs);
```

Comment: Add `.ToArray()` when needed.

Comment: I need to be able to input whatever array I want, not just a fixed one.

Comment: @AirWolf - `.OrderBy()` works on `IEnumerable<>`, so you are covered. When you really (really) need in-place sorting then you should have made that clear.

Comment: Im not sure what exactly I need, that is the core of the problem.

Comment: @AirWolf of course you can pass what you want.. see update

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution.

```
var array = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();

            var sorted = array.OrderBy(Math.Abs);

            foreach (int element in sorted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element);
            }
```

Kind regards,
A classmate?